# AH02579: Init: Private key not found - Apache VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up a virtual host in apache to reverse proxy in Node.js and is giving this error when I try to use SSL certificate, it says it can't find the key, even if I type cd "directory_here" it normally opens the key, why are you showing you can't find it? If the key is there, why not find it?

```
[Wed Aug 21 16:19:53.260952 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 58556] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key domain.net:443:1, check /home/domain/ssl/certs/domain_net.crt
[Wed Aug 21 16:20:05.758834 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 58627] AH02579: Init: Private key not found
[Wed Aug 21 16:20:05.758876 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 58627] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Aug 21 16:20:05.758892 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 58627] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Wed Aug 21 16:20:05.758903 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 58627] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Aug 21 16:20:05.758914 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 58627] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)
[Wed Aug 21 16:20:05.758926 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 58627] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Wed Aug 21 16:20:05.758936 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 58627] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Aug 21 16:20:05.758946 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 58627] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
[Wed Aug 21 16:20:05.758959 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 58627] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key domain.net:443:1, check /home/domain/ssl/certs/domain_net.crt
```

Here is my VirtualHost file

```
ServerName domain.net
ServerAlias www.domain.net

DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html
ErrorLog /home/domain/public_html/nuxtError.log
CustomLog /home/domain/public_html/nuxtAccess.log combined

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyVia Full
<Proxy *>
   Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/domain/ssl/certs/domain_net.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/domain/ssl/keys/domainkey.key
```

Comment: Have you checked permission on file? Does it accessible by Apache?

Comment: Yes, it has the necessary permissions.

Comment: My SO is Cent OS 7

Comment: Why not post the actual permissions of the file instead? ls -l /home/domain/ssl/keys/domainkey.key

Comment: Check the key: openssl rsa -in /home/domain/ssl/keys/domainkey.key -check; Check the certificate: openssl x509 -in /home/domain/ssl/certs/domain_net.crt -text -noout